# How do you really know if you need a rebuit transmission?

Tags: transmission, isuzu

My 1998 Isuzu Trooper sounds funny at 58 MPH hours and sometimes it slips out of gear and jerks back in.   I've taken it to several mechanics and they say it's fine... That's good but I wont a smooth ride and to me it's harsh.

Comment: When was the last time you had the transmission serviced? Did any of the mechanics drain the fluid, change the filter, etc? If not I'd suggest getting it serviced first before you talk about replacing anything.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Also ... What @GdD said! Sounds like you may be starving your transmission of fluid pressure at speed. Getting the filter/fluid changed may help with this.